# Sort Array By Date Using Only Time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsdate

I'm currently sorting an array of objects with a property `startTime` however I have realised that it is sorting by day and time.

So if I add an object and set the time to something earlier than a pre made one, if its made more than a day later it will always be listed after the other. Make sense?

So lets say my NSDate is Tuesday 25th 6:02PM. I want to scratch the Tuesday 26th bit and only sort by time, the day doesn't matter to me. How can I do this?

Thanks.

P.S This is how I am currently sorting my objects:

```
NSSet *tasks = [self.routine task];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sorted = [[tasks allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a category on `NSDate` that returns the time interval since the start of the day for the current calendar and time zone, and then use that time interval to do your sorting.

```
@interface NSDate (CBVAdditions)

- (NSTimeInterval)cbvTimeIntervalSinceStartOfDay;

@end

@implementation NSDate (CBVAdditions)

- (NSTimeInterval)cbvTimeIntervalSinceStartOfDay
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
    [dateComponents setCalendar:calendar];
    [dateComponents setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSInteger hoursComponent = dateComponents.hour * 3600;
    NSInteger minutesComponent = dateComponents.minute * 60;
    double secondsComponent = dateComponents.second;
    NSTimeInterval toReturn = hoursComponent + minutesComponent + secondsComponent;
    return toReturn;
}

@end
```

Then, you can use `NSSortDescriptor` with a key like `@"dateProperty.cbvTimeIntervalSinceStartOfDay"` to do the actual sorting. For example, I show the `Event` class, and some code that accomplishes the sort.

```
@interface Event : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *eventDate;

@end

@implementation Event

- (NSString *)description
{
    NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, name = %@, eventDate = %@",[super description], self.name, [self.eventDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
    return desc;
}
@end

...

Event *e1 = [Event new];
e1.eventDate = [NSDate date];
e1.name = @"e1";
Event *e2 = [Event new];
e2.eventDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-1 * 22 * 3600)];
e2.name = @"e2";
Event *e3 = [Event new];
e3.eventDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
e3.name = @"e3";

NSArray *events = @[e1,e2,e3];
NSLog(@"Events = %@", events);
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"eventDate.cbvTimeIntervalSinceStartOfDay" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedEvents = [events sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
NSLog(@"Sorted Events = %@", sortedEvents);
```

Executing this code presented the following output:

```
2013-01-15 15:50:54.221 DateSortingFun[67319:c07] Events = (
    "<Event: 0x717b050>, name = e1, eventDate = Tuesday, January 15, 2013, 3:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time",
    "<Event: 0x717b620>, name = e2, eventDate = Monday, January 14, 2013, 5:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time",
    "<Event: 0x717b650>, name = e3, eventDate = Tuesday, January 15, 2013, 4:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time" ) 


2013-01-15 15:50:54.222 DateSortingFun[67319:c07] Sorted Events = (
    "<Event: 0x717b050>, name = e1, eventDate = Tuesday, January 15, 2013, 3:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time",
    "<Event: 0x717b650>, name = e3, eventDate = Tuesday, January 15, 2013, 4:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time",
    "<Event: 0x717b620>, name = e2, eventDate = Monday, January 14, 2013, 5:50:54 PM Mountain Standard Time" )
```

Answer (score 4):

use comparison blocks. and in the block create a new data with year, month and date set to the same day. that do a normal compare on those dates.

```
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.year = 2007;
    comps.month = 12;
    comps.day = 3;
    comps.hour = 12;
    comps.minute = 3;

    NSDate *date1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

    comps.year = 2012;
    comps.month = 9;
    comps.day = 7;
    comps.hour = 11;
    comps.minute = 13;

    NSDate *date2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

    comps.year = 2021;
    comps.month = 12;
    comps.day = 3;
    comps.hour = 12;
    comps.minute = 5;

    NSDate *date3 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

    comps.year = 2021;
    comps.month = 12;
    comps.day = 3;
    comps.hour = 13;
    comps.minute = 5;


    NSDate *date4 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSArray *dates = @[date1, date2, date3, date4];

    NSArray *oderedByTimeOnlyDates = [dates sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *d1, NSDate *d2) {
        NSDateComponents *comps1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit| NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
                                                                  fromDate:d1];
        NSDateComponents *comps2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit| NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
                                                                   fromDate:d2];

        NSDate *date1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps1];
        NSDate *date2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps2];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", oderedByTimeOnlyDates);
```

output:

```
(
    "2012-09-07 09:13:00 +0000",
    "2007-12-03 11:03:00 +0000",
    "2021-12-03 11:05:00 +0000",
    "2021-12-03 12:05:00 +0000"
)
```

The output is in UTC time, while they were created in UTC+1.